# Android mediaplayer crashes on exit

Tags: android-mediaplayer

The issue I'm having is MediaPlayer release works fine when I use it within the activity where I load multiple audio files interchangeably. But, when I exit the activity and call release [via onPause()]. it crashes right away. I've tried searching under similar posts, but haven't found a definitive answer, so posting here. The code looks like this:

```
public void closeMediaPlayer()   {
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        }
    }

    public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release(); // crashes on exit
            mp = null;
        }
    }

    public void instantiateMediaPlayer(int resId) {
        closeMediaPlayer();
        releaseMediaPlayer(); // works fine here

        if (mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resId); //resId points to the mp3 audio file
        }
    }

   public void onPause() {
        closeMediaPlayer();
        releaseMediaPlayer(); // crashes here
        super.onPause();
    }
```

I am calling mp.start() in my setOnClickListener() handler. And I'm currently developing and debugging under Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my run() handler, I was doing this:

```
mp.getCurrentPosition();
```

which was the reason for the crash, since I was accessing mp after releasing it. I've put that under a guard now and things are fine. No issues with release whatsoever